# The number of simple zeros of $f(z)=4z^{100}-e^z$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)=4z^{100}-e^z$
I want to find the number of simple zeros in the unit disc $D=\{z \in C \mid |z|<1 \}$

I guess :

By Rouche Theorem, $f(z)$ and $4z^{100}$ have same number of zeros in $D$
Thus $f$ has 100 zeros in $D$.


$f'(z)=400z^{99}-e^z$
Suppose $f=f'=0$, Then $4z^{99}(z-100)=0$, however $z=0$ is not a zero of $f$.

Thus there is no $z \in D$ such that $f(z)=f'(z)=0$

Therefore, All zeros in $D$ are simple.

Is it correct?

Comment: This looks alright.